# Add dynamic created AtmosphereHandler to AtmosphereFramework while runtime

Tags: java, atmosphere

I would like to add dynamic created handler to framework while runtime.

Dynamic created class is `@ManagedService` annotated.

I was trying to use `AtmosphereFramework.addAtmosphereHandler`:

```
Class<?> msaClass = createDynamically();

ManagedService ms = msaClass.getAnnotation(ManagedService.class);
String path = ms.path();

Object c = msaClass.newInstance();

AtmosphereHandler msaHandler = new ManagedAtmosphereHandler(c)
framework.addAtmosphereHandler(path, msaHandler)
```

Also `AnnotationHandler.handleAnnotation` dosen't work too:

```
Class<?> msaClass = createDynamically();
AnnotationHandler.handleAnnotation(framework, ManagedService.class, msaClass)
```

I'm using Atmosphere 2.0.0.RC3, Java 7 and Tomcat 7.0.42